# jQuery onClick not working on the main element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, addclass

I'm trying to add and remove `onclick` a class from an element.

But my function not work becouse it add the class only if the child elements are clicked and remove that class only if the parent is clicked.

I want to move the `.card-header.swipeable` element to show the `.swipe-actions` element and click again to hide.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bacsaav6/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //slide the contact
  $('.card-header.swipeable').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('swipe-left');
  });
  //close the contact
  $('.card-header.swipeable').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.card-header.swipeable') ) { 
      $('.card-header.swipeable').removeClass('swipe-left');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
$('.card-header.swipeable').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if( $('.card-header.swipeable').hasClass('swipe-left') ) { 
      $('.card-header.swipeable').removeClass('swipe-left');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('swipe-left');
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with `toggleClass`:

```
$('.card-header.swipeable').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('swipe-left');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Wow thats work great! there is a way to make it translate a little bit slowly?